# Touch switch with conductive ink as thin as possible

Tags: circuit-design, conductive

First for all. Am not an electrical enginner, am just an amateur artisan, pretending make intetesting gadgets.

So the situation is this. I need to make a circuit in a sheet of paper for just turn on and turn off a very very little led light. The challenge: make this as thin as possible. Ideally with 0.5mm of thickness.

What I already made: I found a very interesting example in this link https://www.electroschematics.com/5996/touch-switch-circuits/

But the problem is, again, the thickness, only the  ic 555 has a 3.5 mm, for me its to much. In summary, is there another way to do this circuit but in a very very thin way?.

Comment: You could get close. http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmc555.pdf Look at page 29. The max height of the DSBGS is 0.575mm. The problem is going to be attaching it and making sure that it's reliable.

Comment: how about a bare-die JFET?

Comment: 5  volts (safe for the human hand) and 100,000 ohms (between fingers)produces 50uA which should make a LED glow.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a *very* weak light, use a neon lamp and a safe, *low current* power supply. Bridging two conductive ink traces between the lamp and supply with a finger would light the lamp. Using audio-frequency or low frequency RF would make the circuit easier to turn on, since it would bypass skin resistance with capacitive coupling.

Answer (score 0):

0.5mm rules out most packaged ICs (that’s about the thickness of a sawn wafer.) If you could use chip-on-board it’s possible, or something in chip-scale packaging you might be able to make that.

That said, a Silego GPAK device gets pretty close, at about 0.75mm.

You didn’t mention your battery - how are you dealing with that?

More: have a look here. Some candidates that meet your criteria possibly. [What are the smallest microcontrollers?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/84800/what-are-the-smallest-microcontrollers)